# htaccess configuration to skip a rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have configurated my htaccess to check and redirect mobile devices to specific web. But I would like to skip this rule if the REQUEST_URI is /page/... (blog url)

I have my .htaccess like this

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile siteRewriteCond with this conditions  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/prototypes/.* 
--> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/.*  
--> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page/.*
RewriteRule ^ http://www.applified.nl/m/web%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteRule ^page/([^/\.]+)/?$ ?page=$1
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/\.]+)/?$ ?page=Blog&entry=$1   [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/Blog/offset/(.+)/?$ ?page=Blog&offset=$1   [NC]
```

I try severals ways but I dont reach any solution

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this the line before the [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page/
```

With [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) the `CondPatern` you choose can be a non-matching pattern if a `!` prefix is used.
Then if the `RewriteCond` is false, the RewriteRule which follow will not be used.

About association between several `RewriteCond`, each condition must be met so the `RewriteRule` which follow is used ( so it's like an AND between each `RewriteCond`, but you can change this behaviour with the [OR] flag at the end of a `RewriteCond` ). So here you can just add the line and it should work out of the box.

Comment: I have tried this way but doesn't work. It can be possible that the configuration of apache server has a conflict with this rule (or write cond) or maybe any cache mem. (I dont have access to server configuration)